# javascript action on click not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to connect to an outsite website when a specific picture is clicked, however it doesn't seem to be functioning... 
here is the **javascript**

```
document.getElementById("connect-health-data-btn").onclick= (HumanConnect.open(options));
```

`connect-health-data-btn` is the `id` of the picture.

However, the script gets run automatically without clicking on the picture. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have created the `onclick` event wrong:

```
document.getElementById("connect-health-data-btn").onclick= function(){HumanConnect.open(options)};
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the question if it was useful )